# Android aplication crash on share button click

Tags: android, button, crash, share

I'm developing an application on android that have a share button on action bar. Previously the button worked fine, but recently this doesn't works anymore, and i'm having problems to debug this issue because after the click the code flow don't stop on any break point. My only hint of the problem is the follow LogCat's errors:

```
07-30 17:52:55.876  16042-16044/igparadaxv.igbparadaxv E/art﹕ Throwing OutOfMemoryError "Failed to allocate a 52 byte allocation with 0 free bytes and 0B until OOM"
07-30 17:52:55.879  16042-16042/igparadaxv.igbparadaxv E/art﹕ Throwing OutOfMemoryError "Failed to allocate a 54 byte allocation with 0 free bytes and 0B until OOM"
07-30 17:52:55.937  16042-16051/igparadaxv.igbparadaxv E/art﹕ Throwing OutOfMemoryError "Failed to allocate a 36 byte allocation with 0 free bytes and 0B until OOM"
07-30 17:52:56.291  16042-16042/igparadaxv.igbparadaxv E/art﹕ Throwing OutOfMemoryError "Failed to allocate a 28 byte allocation with 0 free bytes and 0B until OOM" (recursive case)
07-30 17:52:56.294  16042-16042/igparadaxv.igbparadaxv E/art﹕ "main" prio=5 tid=1 Runnable
07-30 17:52:56.294  16042-16042/igparadaxv.igbparadaxv E/art﹕ | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x74172970 self=0xb4606800
07-30 17:52:56.294  16042-16042/igparadaxv.igbparadaxv E/art﹕ | sysTid=16042 nice=0 cgrp=apps sched=0/0 handle=0xb77b1160
07-30 17:52:56.294  16042-16042/igparadaxv.igbparadaxv E/art﹕ | state=R schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=97 stm=42 core=0 HZ=100
07-30 17:52:56.294  16042-16042/igparadaxv.igbparadaxv E/art﹕ | stack=0xbf43b000-0xbf43d000 stackSize=8MB
07-30 17:52:56.294  16042-16042/igparadaxv.igbparadaxv E/art﹕ | held mutexes= "mutator lock"(shared held)
07-30 17:52:56.294  16042-16042/igparadaxv.igbparadaxv E/art﹕ native: #00 pc 00005ac3  /system/lib/libbacktrace_libc++.so (UnwindCurrent::Unwind(unsigned int, ucontext*)+83)
07-30 17:52:56.295  16042-16042/igparadaxv.igbparadaxv E/art﹕ native: #01 pc 00002e91  /system/lib/libbacktrace_libc++.so (Backtrace::Unwind(unsigned int, ucontext*)+33)
07-30 17:52:56.295  16042-16042/igparadaxv.igbparadaxv E/art﹕ native: #02 pc 003c3f3a  /system/lib/libart.so (art::DumpNativeStack(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, int, char const*, art::mirror::ArtMethod*)+138)
07-30 17:52:56.295  16042-16042/igparadaxv.igbparadaxv E/art﹕ native: #03 pc 0038d03c  /system/lib/libart.so (art::Thread::DumpStack(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&) const+268)
07-30 17:52:56.295  16042-16042/igparadaxv.igbparadaxv E/art﹕ native: #04 pc 0039142b  /system/lib/libart.so (art::Thread::ThrowOutOfMemoryError(char const*)+459)
07-30 17:52:56.295  16042-16042/igparadaxv.igbparadaxv E/art﹕ native: #05 pc 001ec6fb  /system/lib/libart.so (art::gc::Heap::ThrowOutOfMemoryError(art::Thread*, unsigned int, art::gc::AllocatorType)+1243)
07-30 17:52:56.295  16042-16042/igparadaxv.igbparadaxv E/art﹕ native: #06 pc 001f030d  /system/lib/libart.so (art::gc::Heap::AllocateInternalWithGc(art::Thread*, art::gc::AllocatorType, unsigned int, unsigned int*, unsigned int*, art::mirror::Class**)+2749)
07-30 17:52:56.295  16042-16042/igparadaxv.igbparadaxv E/art﹕ native: #07 pc 00176b91  /system/lib/libart.so (art::mirror::Class::AllocObject(art::Thread*)+1329)
07-30 17:52:56.295  16042-16042/igparadaxv.igbparadaxv E/art﹕ native: #08 pc 003905de  /system/lib/libart.so (art::Thread::ThrowNewWrappedException(art::ThrowLocation const&, char const*, char const*)+830)
07-30 17:52:56.295  16042-16042/igparadaxv.igbparadaxv E/art﹕ native: #09 pc 003914d2  /system/lib/libart.so (art::Thread::ThrowOutOfMemoryError(char const*)+626)
07-30 17:52:56.295  16042-16042/igparadaxv.igbparadaxv E/art﹕ native: #10 pc 001ec6fb  /system/lib/libart.so (art::gc::Heap::ThrowOutOfMemoryError(art::Thread*, unsigned int, art::gc::AllocatorType)+1243)
07-30 17:52:56.295  16042-16042/igparadaxv.igbparadaxv E/art﹕ native: #11 pc 001f030d  /system/lib/libart.so (art::gc::Heap::AllocateInternalWithGc(art::Thread*, art::gc::AllocatorType, unsigned int, unsigned int*, unsigned int*, art::mirror::Class**)+2749)
07-30 17:52:56.295  16042-16042/igparadaxv.igbparadaxv E/art﹕ native: #12 pc 0031aabf  /system/lib/libart.so (art::mirror::String::Alloc(art::Thread*, int)+1903)
07-30 17:52:56.295  16042-16042/igparadaxv.igbparadaxv E/art﹕ native: #13 pc 0031b0fc  /system/lib/libart.so (art::mirror::String::AllocFromModifiedUtf8(art::Thread*, char const*)+44)
07-30 17:52:56.295  16042-16042/igparadaxv.igbparadaxv E/art﹕ native: #14 pc 0038f9ff  /system/lib/libart.so (art::Thread::InternalStackTraceToStackTraceElementArray(art::ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnable const&, _jobject*, _jobjectArray*, int*)+383)
07-30 17:52:56.295  16042-16042/igparadaxv.igbparadaxv E/art﹕ native: #15 pc 00340650  /system/lib/libart.so (art::Throwable_nativeGetStackTrace(_JNIEnv*, _jclass*, _jobject*)+80)
07-30 17:52:56.295  16042-16042/igparadaxv.igbparadaxv E/art﹕ native: #16 pc 00000fe6  /data/dalvik-cache/x86/system@framework@boot.oat (Java_java_lang_Throwable_nativeGetStackTrace__Ljava_lang_Object_2+142)
07-30 17:52:56.296  16042-16042/igparadaxv.igbparadaxv E/art﹕ at java.lang.Throwable.nativeGetStackTrace!(Native method)
07-30 17:52:56.296  16042-16042/igparadaxv.igbparadaxv E/art﹕ at java.lang.Throwable.getInternalStackTrace(Throwable.java:264)
07-30 17:52:56.296  16042-16042/igparadaxv.igbparadaxv E/art﹕ at java.lang.Throwable.printStackTrace(Throwable.java:318)
07-30 17:52:56.296  16042-16042/igparadaxv.igbparadaxv E/art﹕ at java.lang.Throwable.printStackTrace(Throwable.java:300)
07-30 17:52:56.296  16042-16042/igparadaxv.igbparadaxv E/art﹕ at android.util.Log.getStackTraceString(Log.java:335)
07-30 17:52:56.296  16042-16042/igparadaxv.igbparadaxv E/art﹕ at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.Clog_e(RuntimeInit.java:59)
07-30 17:52:56.296  16042-16042/igparadaxv.igbparadaxv E/art﹕ at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.access$200(RuntimeInit.java:43)
07-30 17:52:56.296  16042-16042/igparadaxv.igbparadaxv E/art﹕ at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$UncaughtHandler.uncaughtException(RuntimeInit.java:85)
07-30 17:52:56.296  16042-16042/igparadaxv.igbparadaxv E/art﹕ at java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:693)
07-30 17:52:56.296  16042-16042/igparadaxv.igbparadaxv E/art﹕ at java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:690)
07-30 17:52:56.296  16042-16042/igparadaxv.igbparadaxv E/art﹕ [ 07-30 17:52:56.315 16042:16051 I/art      ]
    Clamp target GC heap from 68MB to 64MB
07-30 17:52:56.379  16042-16042/? E/AndroidRuntime﹕ Error reporting crash
    java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: OutOfMemoryError thrown while trying to throw OutOfMemoryError; no stack available
```

Anybody had any suggestion of what is the problem?

**[EDIT]**

i'm using the follow code:

fotoDetalheActivity.java

```
package igparadaxv.igbparadaxv;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.view.MenuItemCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.support.v7.widget.ShareActionProvider;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.text.Normalizer;
import java.util.zip.Inflater;

import uk.co.senab.photoview.PhotoViewAttacher;

/**
 * Created by Jarves on 19/07/2015.
 */
public class fotoDetalheActivity extends Fragment{

    OnFotoSelecionadaListener mCallback;
    public static String Url;
    public static String Nome;
    Activity activity;

    ImageView expandedImageView;
    ImageButton download,compartilhar;
    private ShareActionProvider mShareActionProvider;
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);

    public interface OnFotoSelecionadaListener {
        public void OnFotoSelecionada(String Url, String nome);
    }

    public fotoDetalheActivity(){

    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity)
    {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        this.activity = activity;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Fotos IBPXV");

        Bundle bundle = this.getArguments();
        if (bundle != null) {
            this.Url = bundle.getString("Url");

            if( bundle.getString("Nome").length()<20)
            {
                this.Nome = bundle.getString("Nome").replaceAll("\\p{C}", "?");
            }else {
                this.Nome = bundle.getString("Nome").replaceAll("\\p{C}", "?").substring(0, 20);
            }
        }

    }

      @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fotodetalhe, container, false);
    }


    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        expandedImageView = (ImageView) getView().findViewById(R.id.imgDetalhe);
        download = (ImageButton) getView().findViewById(R.id.btnDownload);
        download.setOnClickListener(clicado);

        compartilhar = (ImageButton) getView().findViewById(R.id.btnShare);
        compartilhar.setOnClickListener(clicado);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
        OnFotoSelecionada(Url);
    }

    public void OnFotoSelecionada(String Url) {

        Picasso.with(getActivity()).load(Url).into(expandedImageView);

        PhotoViewAttacher mAttacher = new PhotoViewAttacher(expandedImageView);

    }

    // Call to update the share intent
    private Intent setShareIntent(Uri endereco, File foto) {
        // If you want to share a png image only, you can do:
        // setType("image/png"); OR for jpeg: setType("image/jpeg");
        intent.setType("image/*");

        // Make sure you put example png image named myImage.png in your
        // directory
        Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(foto);
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, endereco);

        return intent;

    }

    private void compartilhar() {

        expandedImageView.buildDrawingCache();
        Bitmap bm = expandedImageView.getDrawingCache();

        OutputStream fOut = null;
        Uri outputFileUri;
        File sdImageMainDirectory;
        try {
            File root = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                    + File.separator + "IBPXV" + File.separator);
            root.mkdirs();
            sdImageMainDirectory = new File(root,Nome+".jpg");
            outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile(sdImageMainDirectory);
            fOut = new FileOutputStream(sdImageMainDirectory);

            bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fOut);
            fOut.flush();
            fOut.close();

            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(setShareIntent(outputFileUri, sdImageMainDirectory), "Compartilhar!"));


        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Erro enviando imagem.",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }

    }

    View.OnClickListener clicado = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            switch (v.getId()) {
                case R.id.btnShare:
                    compartilhar();
                    break;


            }
        }
    };

    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {

        // Inflate menu resource file.
        getActivity().getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menufotodetalhe, menu);

        // Locate MenuItem with ShareActionProvider
        MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_item_share);

        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu,inflater);
    }

    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle presses on the action bar items
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.menu_item_share:
                compartilhar();
                return true;

            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

}
```

menufotodetalhe.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_item_share"
        android:actionProviderClass="android.widget.ShareActionProvider"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
        android:title="@string/baixar"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_share_white_48dp"
        />
</menu>
```

Comment: What are you sharing ?

Comment: Sharing images, but when i click the button the event isn't handle, the application crash in the act of click, any image manipulation is made before the fail. I tried to put the same button in others fragments only to see the click event but the application continue to crash.

Comment: Can you post the code you are using to share.
It is difficult to figure out where without the code but code is causing out of memory issue as per your log.